# Calculating covariance matrix from given vertices of triangles

Tags: pca, covariance-matrix, geometry

I am given 3D vertices of triangles and I want to build the covariance matrix from it. These vertices are pure geometric vertices no noise.

I can easily get it from libraries of python but I wanted to understand how under the hood it is calculated.

As per my understanding,
I have list of triangles that forms my samples.
The vertices of triangles are variables lets call it x, y , z.

So what we want is cov(x, y ,z).
This means the covariance matrix that I will derive will answer
how much of x, y , z vary together.

is this right? (would love if someone can answer it)
If it is right then can some one give derivation for covariance matrix?

Thanks

Thanks

Comment: You need to be more specific. Are these given 3D vertices noisy measurements of the true vertices? Assuming they are, do you want to build a sample covariance matrix or the true covariance matrix, assuming you know how these noisy measurements are distributed? Finally, since you can obtain the same triangle by translation or rotation, what spatial constraints are there on these vertices?

Comment: These are true vertices. I am not sure I understand difference between sample covariance matrix and true covariance matrix. which one would we use if my final aim is to do PCA. Also can you elaborate spatial constraint ?

Comment: You write that "*I have list of triangles that forms my samples.*", which suggests that your vertices are random across triangles and not per triangle. Suppose that one triangle is described by the points $\{(0,0,0),(0,0,1),(0,1,0)\}$. If you translate this triangle 1 unit along the x-axis, you get the points $\{(1,0,0),(1,0,1),(1,1,0)\}$. The triangle before the translation and the triangle after the translation have the same edge lengths, but they are off by 1 unit. Are you considering these as two different triangles? A rotation would also yield the same edge lengths.